# Why are the version / build numbers different for Mylyn?

Tags: versioning, eclipse

At [projects.eclipse.org](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/release/1.1.0-8) Mylyn Build 1.1.0 is slated for June 2013.
At [www.eclipse.org/mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) The "news" says Mylyn 3.8.3 was released on March 1st.

Why is there little or no correlation between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mylyn Builds** is just one of the components of **Mylyn**, it's description reads:

> Integration of continuous integration and build systems and seamless
>   access to software build and assembly technologies. Mylyn users will
>   be able to access continuous integration processes, control build
>   execution and associate build results with tasks and context.

Version 3.8.3 refers to Mylyn in general, while version 1.1.0 refers to Builds component.